# Teams: Personal Tab => successful authentication redirects back to login page (Due to cookie not being set)

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-teams

So we have this web application running, but we wanted to make a Teams app (personal tab) from it. We used App Studio to create the app (manifest and all), but when running it from the sidebar we won't get past the login screen. On successful login, you get redirected back to the login page (everything happens on the same domain).

But when we tried to run the "app" as a tab within a group, this worked. So we need to find out why this doesn't work when we run it as a Teams "app".

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you seeing the login page on page reload?

Comment: I figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that since it's running inside an iframe (in practice), the cookie set by ASP.NET State needs to state SameSite="None" and Secure="true".

> Applications that use `<iframe>` may experience issues with sameSite=Lax or sameSite=Strict cookies because `<iframe>` is treated as cross-site scenarios. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

So I had to upgrade the .NET Target Framework to 4.7.2, and make the changes stated in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

Comment: Nice one figuring this out

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow: Contradicting statements here in this post and in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab.                        Based on this post: the cookie set by ASP.NET State needs to state SameSite="None" and Secure="true". But based on official documentation: Teams desktop client or older versions of Chrome or Safari do not support SameSite=None.

Comment: Could you avoid ASP.Net state altogether? I don't think it would work across devices for the user anyway - maybe rather try store whatever you need based on the user's AadObjectId or similar, which would be consistent across devices

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru hehe, jepp. I did extend this application and saw that as well. Quite confusing, but was able to manage authentication within teams using the microsoft teams sdk

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I had to later on change the standalone application to be part of an existing (quite large) .NET Framework application so i couldn't avoid ASP.NET state. 

It got weird pretty quick since i developed a web application to run in an iframe on this large project (to remove some complexity). But ended up needing to use the output static files directly and write a seperate teams authentication solution to make it work within a teams (personal tab) app